# I need to create a second Google Account

Tags: google-ads, accounts

I need to create an additional Google Account for a new business. What is the best way to structure it?

Comment: This does very much come under: Why do you need another account? Do you mean a separate Google login? Or a separate Ads account? Or do you want an account _for_ your new business separate from your personal Google account? You've tagged this for Ads, but not mentioned it in your question itself, could you clarify that you mean a new Google Ads account or not.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it appears to be about using Google and not about running a website.

Answer (score 2):

If your original Google Ads account got suspended/shutdown due to violations of some kind, then I don't fancy your chances.

There are limited circumstances in which Google will allow the creation and use of 2nd Google Ads account, however you will need to contact a Google Ads support rep or contact a 3rd party Google Ads partner (they offer paid assistance), in order to have it all setup correctly and not end up in violation of their policies resulting in the new Google Ads account ending up with a suspension too.